# Groovy/Ant: Zipping two files in a Groovy-loop in an ant Task

Tags: ant, groovy, zip

i have following problem:
1.) I have to files 12345678.xml-out and 12345678.xml and i want them to be zipped into 12345.zip.
The problem is i have a loop because there can be more than one of such pairs in that directory:

```
<target>
    <groovy>

    import java.util.regex.Pattern
    import java.util.regex.Matcher

    (...)   
        f.eachFileMatch { it.split("\\.")[1].length()==7 } {
            (.. do something and then zip)

                def ant = new AntBuilder() 
ant.zip(
    destfile: "C:/temp.zip", 
    fileset: HERE I NEED A PATTERN MATCH with the GROOVY it variable...
)
        }   

    </groovy>

</target>
```

2.) General question: Is there a possibility to use groovy variables in an antBuilder object??

Comment: could you use something like this to do the zipping instead? http://commons.apache.org/compress/examples.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does something like this work?

```
<target>
  <groovy>
    def ant = new AntBuilder()
    def pattern = ~/([0-9]{7}).xml/
    def base = new File( '.' )
    base.eachFileMatch( pattern ) { f ->
      def prefix = ( f.name =~ pattern )[0][1]
      ant.zip(
        basedir: base,
        destfile: "${prefix}.zip", 
        includes: "${prefix}.xml,${prefix}.xml-out"
      )
    }   
  </groovy>
</target>
```